# PHP Form to submit multple rows for each product

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a page that will have a form on it. When the form is submtited I would like to submit all the content from the input fields, but I also would like to post duplicate information where the Products change.

For example..

If a user inputs the following

Name
Address
Phone Number
First Product
Second Product
Third Product

it will post to my database sql.

`| John Doe | 123 Cherry Lane | 555-555-5555 | Product 1 |`

`| John Doe | 123 Cherry Lane | 555-555-5555 | Product 2 |`

`| John Doe | 123 Cherry Lane | 555-555-5555 | Product 3 |`

I know how to get the php form submitting, how would I structure a foreach?

Can someone show me an example of how I would achieve this.
Everything I find is looking to prevent this, but I want it.

Comment: Could you show, please, what you have tried so far?

Comment: I cant show you an example. I haven't built it yet. I am trying to do some home work (no not school work) on how to do it. I have other forms that I have created but I only need them to post 1 tbl row.

Comment: @Levi are you inserting this values to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with code. First of all count product item then `for loop`

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Name:    <input type="text" name="input[0][name]" value="">
Address:  <input type="text" name="input[0][address]" value="">
Mobile: <input type="text" name="input[0][mobile]" value="">
Product <input type="text" name="product[0][product]" value="">
Product1 <input type="text" name="product[1][product]" value="">
Product2 <input type="text" name="product[2][product]" value="">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">


<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $input = $_POST['input'];
    $product = $_POST['product'];   
    if(!empty($input) && !empty($product)){
    for($i=0; $i<count($product); $i++){        
        $fname = $input[0]['name'];
        $address = $input[0]['address'];
        $mobile = $input[0]['mobile'];
        $product = $product[$i]['product'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (id, name, address, mobile, product) VALUES('', '$fname' , '$address', '$mobile' , '$product')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
           echo "New record created successfully";
         } else {
           echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
       }

       mysqli_close($conn);

    }
}
}    
?>
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the connection lines please. @Jakir Hossain

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the one better idea to get the benefit of mysql relationship.
First create two different table..
 1. users
 2. user_product 
Then, when you submitting form you have to first post data in users table and then get this user id and post data in to user_product table with user_id.
Let me here describe two table.

### Users

1. id(pk)
2. name
3. address
4. phone_number

   ### user_product
5. id(PK)
6. user_id(references of users table id)
7. product

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try to this code

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Name:    <input type="text" name="input[0][name]" value="">
Address:  <input type="text" name="input[0][address]" value="">
Mobile: <input type="text" name="input[0][mobile]" value="">
Product <input type="text" name="input[0][product]" value="">
Product1 <input type="text" name="input[1][product]" value="">
Product2 <input type="text" name="input[2][product]" value="">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">


<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $input = $_POST['input'];

    foreach($input as $values) {
        if(!empty($values['name']) && !empty($values['address']) && !empty($values['mobile']) && !empty($values['product'])) {
            $insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO varify (id,name, address, mobile,product) VALUES('', ?, ?, ?,?)');
            $insert->bind_value('11', $values['name'], $values['address'], $values['mobile'],$values['product']);
            $insert->execute();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the connection lines please. @Kalpesh Kikani

Comment: @Kalpesh Kikani $values['product'] did not show multiple item because above condition is first time loop right and second time is not right.